# I need help translating two sentences into Latin

Tags: classical-latin

Phrase 1 : Life is in the doing.
Phrase 2 : The wood belongs to the families who have their roots in it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you please split your question in two? You have two separate questions, so they should be asked separately. (The question can be reopened after that.) Also, please explain the message you are trying to convey with these sentences in both questions. Translation depends on context, and people are more willing to help if you put more effort into your question.

Comment: I'm having a problem with your second aphorism, though the meaning is admirable. 'Roots in the forest,' *Radices in Silva,'* also unfortunately means 'the radishes in the wood;' or even rhubarb: *radix punica.* But do please present your questions again and we shall solve the problems.